# Left Join to top 1 using LINQ to entites

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a list of entities that each have 0 > n associated reviews. I want to join the latest review, if one exists for each entity. I then want to return the status of the latest review as below, but not able to filter lstReviews down to the top 1 by CreatedDate Descending.

```
 var lstMainEntity = this.service.GetAllMainEntities();
 var lstReviews = this.service.GetReviews();

 var lst = from e in lstMainEntity 
           from review in lstReviews.Where(r => r.EntityID == e.EntityID).DefaultIfEmpty()   
  select new 
  {
      ID = e.EntityID,
      ReviewStatus = review != null ? review.IsComplete ? "Complete" : "Active"
  }
```

How can i best achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `lstMainEntity` and `lstReviews` are `IQueryable<..>`. If they are `IEnumerable<..>`, you will have to put a null check in the `ReviewStatus` assignment. (Performance should be faster if it is an `IQueryable`)

```
  var lst = from e in lstMainEntity 
            let review = lstReviews.Where(r => r.EntityID == e.EntityID)
                                   .OrderByDescending(r => r.CreatedDate)
                                   .FirstOrDefault()
  select new 
  {
      ID = e.EntityID,
      ReviewStatus = review.IsComplete ? "Complete" : "Active"
  }
```